# CmdlineEnter vs CmdwinEnter (In the context of changing Cmdline background color)

Tags: neovim, autocmd, cmdline

Firstly, Im using NeoVim (as you can tell by the `winhighlight` command). When entering the command line by pressing `:`, I change the command line window foreground/background. The following very ugly hack works for me:

```
augroup mythemecmdLine
    autocmd!
    autocmd CmdlineEnter : set winhighlight=Normal:Normal | redraw | hi! Normal guifg=black guibg=white
    autocmd CmdlineLeave : hi Normal guifg=white guibg=black
augroup END
```

It relies on the rest of the screen not being redrawn until exiting the command line window. What I dont understand the difference between `CmdlineEnter` vs `CmdwinEnter`. The above code only works for the former. Reading the `:help` on each one leaves me with the impression that `CmdwinEnter` is only triggered when one types commands, whereas `CmdLineEnter` is triggered by scripts too. However with my code snipped above, even when I type `:`  the autocmd `CmdwinEnter` is not fired.

Reading the help I can't figure out what the distincition is between the command line and command line window, my impression is they are the same thing, which I assume must be a wrong assumption.

I can't get `CmdwinEnter` to fire, so what is it's purpose?

Comment: Do you know about the command window? q: or :Ctrl-f?

Comment: Ah ha! Yes I do,  but didn't click it was refering to that. Just tested it and it does exactly what you say. Thanks again Ben!! Are you like employed by stackexchange or made millions by bitcoin?? So glad you are here!

Comment: lol no just a guy with a passion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event    `CmdLineEnter` refers to entering the command line via `:`, `/`, or `?`, including non-interactively.

There is also `CmdWinEnter`, referring to entering the command window. There are 2 ways for each type of command like above to enter the command window:

1. `q` followed by the command (e.g., `q:`), or
2. From any of the command lines, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd>

Comment: CmdLineEnter is also triggered when the cmd line is entered non-interactively.